# Does MPMoviePlayerController support AVI format in iOS?

Tags: ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, avi

I'm able to play .mp4, .m4v formats using MPMoviePlayerController, but its not playing .avi format. MPMoviePlayerController internally would use QuickTimePlayer and this QuicktimePlayer would support AVI format, then y not MPMoviePLayerController API?

Thank You, 
Suse

Answer (score 1):

AVI is a container format. It can contain many different audio/video formats internally, most of which iOS does not support natively.

You may be able to decode the contents of your .AVI using the ffmpeg library. Note, however, that decoding video using ffmpeg will drain the battery considerably faster than normal, as it cannot take advantage of the hardware acceleration that MPEG4 decoding uses, and using ffmpeg may subject your application to software licensing complications (as ffmpeg is licensed under LGPL, with some GPL and non-free components).

Comment: Can you please provide me the link to ffmpeg library?[API should be for iOS, Objective-C]

Comment: http://ffmpeg.org/ - note that it is a C library, not Objective-C; and that that it isn't trivial to use.

Comment: This AVI contains a raw video format and there is no audio contents in it. Is there a posibility of MPMoviePlayerCOntroller decoding this AVI format?